# ¿Cómo cargar/retornar determinado controlador -> método según un valor en una ruta en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

Tengos dos métodos que efectúan diferentes acciones, requiero cargar cada uno de ellos respecto al rol que tiene el usuario, si por ejemplo el rol del usuario es 1 cargue un método, si es 2 cargo otro, esto hacerlo en la ruta de laravel, algo así:

```
 Route::get('productos', function (){
    if (Auth::user()->rol == 1) {
        //Cargar método x
    } else if (Auth::user()->rol == 2){
        //Cargar método y
    }
 });
```

Generalmente hago que se cargue un determinado método por ruta con:

```
Route::get('productos', [ProductosController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: Creo que en este caso, lo mejor es que utilices un **middleware**, en el compruebes que rol tiene el usuario actual y redirigirlo a otra ruta en caso de que sea necesario (que no sea esa la ruta que le corresponda), porque hacer uso de controladores arbitrarios  en rutas no me parece correcto y además creo que no es  posible

Comment: E incluso puedes hacer uso de una ruta intermedia que se encargue solo de eso, redirigir a la ruta correspondiente

Answer (score 0):

No se si ya estas usando esto pero te recomiendo laravel-permission de spatie [En su documentacion te muestran como trabajar los roles y hacer lo que preguntas](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).